# Android - How to make loading on first starting

Tags: android

Hi it's my first question in stackoverflow sorry if i do something wrong.

My problem is that when i start the app for very first time i need to write the SQL data in the database. If i do that in onCreate() while it's writing the sql it's not showing the View so it's like freezing. And if i make loader there it's not showed because first of all ti want's to finish all the oncreate and after that to show the View. Then i made AlertDialog to run if SQL is empty to inform the user that in needs "instalation" and after confirm i wanted to make loading box while it's running inserting the SQL...

So my question is : How to make loading onCreate... at running of the activity... can u give me some good idea... here is the code i made:

```
private DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    context = this;     

    if(db.getWordsCount() == 0)
    {           
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Instalation needed");
        builder.setMessage("Database need to be installed");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", dialogClickListener);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Close", dialogClickListener);
        builder.show();
    }
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        switch (which){ 
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
              progress.setTitle("Instalation");
              progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
                progress.show();                
                db.insertWords(db);
                progress.cancel();
            break; 

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE: 
            finish();
            break; 
        } 
    } 
};
```

Comment: Maybe create an AsyncTask (separate thread) that does the database-part. You could make a loading screen in the main UI thread that stops when the task is finished.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lots of example for same :

http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/android-database-example-database-usage-asynctask-database-export/

```
private class InsertDataTask extends AsyncTask {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                DatabaseActivity.this);

        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Inserting data...");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
        protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
            DatabaseActivity.this.application.getDataHelper().insert(args[0]);
            return null;
        }

        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
            // reset the output view by retrieving the new data
            // (note, this is a naive example, in the real world it might make sense
            // to have a cache of the data and just append to what is already there, or such
            // in order to cut down on expensive database operations)
            new SelectDataTask().execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: DatabaseActivity in-place of this use your activity name

Comment: Good answer. You should understand this AsyncTask as being declared inside an Activity of yours called DatabaseActivity. Then you should mark as the correct answer.